# The position of the elements do not remain the same compared to their previous placed position using getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, getboundingclientrect

I drag and drop some elements on a div(containing background image) and upload the content . Before uploading I calculate the dropped element top,left positions wrt to parent div, so that the top,left positions can be used to place the elements exactly at the same place when they are rendered on a different screen along with the background-image(png or jpeg) being passed. But the issue is the elements are placed in a slightly different position compared to their initial placed position.

HTML
Before Uploading

```
<div id="toget"
     class="dropzone"
     [ngStyle]="{'width':'100%',
                 'background-image': 'url('+urlFloorZoneIn+')',
                 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                 'background-position': 'center',
                 'background-size': '100% 100%',
                 'border':'1px solid black',
                 'height':'340px',
                 'position': 'relative'}">

    <div class="box"
         *ngFor="let existingZone of existingDroppedItemZoneIn"
         [ngStyle] = "{'position': 'absolute' , 
                       'top.%':existingZone.spans[1], 
                       'left.%':existingZone.spans[0]}"
         (dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event,existingZone)">

          {{ existingZone.main }}
        <span>{{existingZone.spans[0]}}</span>
        <span>{{existingZone.spans[1]}}</span>

    </div>

</div>
```

TS code for calculating the top,left positions

```
onDragEnd(event,b){


    const existingMovingBlockIndex = (this.existingDroppedItemZoneIn.indexOf(this.currentBox));
    if(existingMovingBlockIndex>-1){
        console.log(b)
        console.log(`got drag end x and y ${event.clientX} ${event.clientY}`)
        console.log(this.dr.onDragMove);

        const container_rect = this.parentparent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.mouse.x = event.clientX - container_rect.left;
        this.mouse.y = event.clientY - container_rect.top;

        const{width,height} = this.parentparent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const perc_x = this.mouse.x / width * 100;
        const perc_y = this.mouse.y / height * 100;

        this.left = perc_x-5;
        this.topLeft = []
        this.topLeft.push(this.left);

        this.top = perc_y-5;
        this.topLeft.push(this.top);

        this.existingDroppedItemZoneIn[existingMovingBlockIndex].spans[0] = (perc_x);
        this.existingDroppedItemZoneIn[existingMovingBlockIndex].spans[1] = (perc_y);


    }
}
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: rgba(254, 249, 247, 1);
  border: 1.5px solid #e24301;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.dropzone {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: lightgray;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Before rendering I get the top,left, background-image values of the above uploaded HTML content and apply the **background-image**, **top**, **left** values to render the below content

After rendering in different screen

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
<ul>
    <li #allFloors
       *ngFor="let floor of buildings.floors"
       [ngStyle]="{'width': singleFloorFlagStyle ?'40%':'100%',
                   'background-image': 'url('+floor.urlFloorZoneIn+')', 
                   'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                   'background-position': 'center',
                   'background-size': '100% 100%',
                   'border':'1px solid black',
                   'height': singleFloorFlagStyle ? '340px' : '700px', 
                   'position': 'relative', 'max-width': '80%'}"
                   [ngClass]="{'width':'80% !important'}">

            <span (click)="loadFloorInfo(floor._id)">{{ floor.name }}</span>
            <div class="fs-heatmap-wrapper__content__box"
                *ngFor="let existingZone of floor.droppeditem"
                [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute',
                            'top.%': existingZone.spans[1],
                            'left.%': existingZone.spans[0]}">

                {{ existingZone.main }}
             </div>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.fs-heatmap-wrapper {
display: grid;
*min-height: 800px;
&__content {
    padding: 70px 40px 0;
    min-height: 300px;
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        li {
            list-style: none;
            min-width: 48%;
            margin: 12px;
            margin-bottom: 2.5%;
            span {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: #fff;
                text-align: left;
                font-weight: 800;
                font-size: 0.9rem;
                letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
                position: relative;
                top: -30px;
            }
        }
    }

&__box{
width: 100px;       
height: 100px;      
background: rgba(254, 249, 247, 1);     
border: 1.5px solid #e24301;        
margin: 5px;        
line-height: 100px;     
text-align: center;     
font-size: 0.8rem;

    }
  }        
}
```

Comment: @kaiido any suggestions please.

Comment: not sure what i am saying is correct but a think you will get the point to investigate this way. getboundingclientrect is relative to the window, as some absolute positionning are involved, if the drop zone is not at the exact same position in the window as the rendering zone, the dropped element may appear at a different positions in dropzone and rendering while it remain at the same place in the window.

Comment: I'll update the ts code for calculating , it places the child elements at a slightly different position.

Comment: I am calculating the top,left wrt to the dropzone class div, so I think it should place exactly at the same position but it slightly places off from the original

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp Note: The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area is taken into account when computing the bounding rectangle. This means that the rectangle's edges (top, left, bottom, and right) change their values every time the scrolling position changes.

Comment: ok :) , so how can I tackle such situation and also I havent scrolled at the time of uploading , please suggest , and also do padding , margin also affects the correct positioning of the element, thanks

Comment: or maybe a scale problem on the second screenshot it also appear to be bigger. I dont know where it comes from, but on my screen (phone) the upper left room seems to be a square on the second screenshot but not at all on the first one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198380/discussion-between-enthu-and-tuckbros).

Comment: Yeah in different screen I will have to render in 2 divs of different sizes , but the one which I have given here I guess they are of the same size , and as I mentioned it goes a little bit off the mark

Comment: And one more thing when before uploading the position of the elements where I place them differs when I rerender them on the same screen , atleast then it should be at same position , right , where I am going wrong I am not able to understand

Comment: The different screen where I would be rendering on , the divs sizes are fixed(I mean I know in advance what the divs sizes would be in which I would place the bg-image and child elements) , so may be if I can apply some calculation to compensate for the exact positioning

Comment: In ts code I have already done , const perc_x = this.mouse.x / width * 100;
        const perc_y = this.mouse.y / height * 100;

        this.left = perc_x-5; the -5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where the problem is reproducible?

Comment: @LajosArpad I have a stackblitz where the drag drop(custom directives) and top,left calculation is there , but the upload download is not there , would that be sufficient :) , thanks

Comment: @LajosArpad , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3whvic?file=src/app/hello.component.ts , please click on ToGetExistingItem button in stackblitz, thanks

Comment: @Enthu just woke up, desperately grabbing coffey, but will look into it.

Comment: @LajosArpad , thanks alot , I am tensed whether this is achievable or not , I think it should be as everything else looks to be working only the accurate positioning is the issue, thanks alot for your reply :)

Comment: When I click on ToGetExistingItem, 301 and 302 are disappearing. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Also, the getBoundingClientRect function will return the size of the element when the function is being called. It seems like the size changes when the actual content is uploaded. So, a resize might happen between your call to this function and the actual display. That would explain the zoom difference between your expectation and the result. I suspect that since all this involves some HTML elements a CSS solution should exist, but if I were you I would work with an svg generator or a canvas.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yeah 301,302 will be only inside grey area

Comment: @LajosArpad, If with html and css I can handle please suggest , else with svg or canvas how will I implement in angular as also further I would also provide resizing functionality to the boxes , so I was thinking of going b the current approach , thanks

Comment: A CSS & HTML solution (if possible) would encompass you finding out which element's size has increased and to ensure that your specific element will keep its size even when an image is displayed inside of it. It's a slow and difficult process, but I think it should lead to success eventually. As about SVG and canvas options, you can easily generate them with Javascript, so I would suggest that you write your own Javascript library which will handle your specific problems and then use them.

Comment: Helpful tools: https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/ and http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198399/discussion-between-enthu-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C - Draggable Element, P - Drop Zone Parent

**The issue is that you are using mouse's Pointer Position to calculate the new position of C relative to P while the actual source of truth for C's position is:**

```
C.getBoundingClientRect().left - P.parent.getBoundingClientRect().left
```

The mouse pointer could be placed anywhere over C. Let's say I start dragging C by keeping the mouse pointed in the center of C so the event.clientX that you get is not the updated position from where C starts rendering relative to client but it's instead:

```
(clientPosition of C + (clientPosition of Mouse Pointer - clientPosition of C))
```

which is definitely not ClientPosition of C.

So just using the first formula would correct your position. You can assign ids to Draggable Elements and then access them.

Also in your Stackblitz example you use both transform and position on the Dragged element once the Drag has ended which also adds to incorrect position. Use either one of them.

Comment: The first formula will give you the correct calculations but you can't use it with transform still in place. You'll have to either keep the transform attribute or the top, left attributes. Also your parent div is not relative in your stackblitz example.

Comment: Please refer tot the updated stackblitz,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5doank?file=src/app/hello.component.html

Comment: If it's an array then use index as unique identifier for element ids. To get the top and left getBoundingClientRect is the easiest way out. Access elements through document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the reason for this issue is the top and left property that you have provided in %. Rather than converting the values into %, try using them directly in pixels.

Comment: I thought % would give me more fine grain control , as in the other screen I would be placing the boxes in  2 different size of grey divs , that is the reason I thought % would give automatically place the boxes irrespective of the parent grey div size

Comment: Hmm True. Then probably you should check the width of those parent grey divs(which i am assuming are the floors with the bg image). As per your code, width of a floor is 80%, which you have specified in ngClass. Would be cool if you could share the code

Comment: The code I have already provided in the post and the stackblitz is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qfhdz?file=src/app/hello.component.ts